# Integration test get ActionController::UrlGenerationError in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

Im new to rails : ( 
Trying to write some test for editing the user's booking info, here are what i get,i have checked on other posts on stackover , it seems unrelated Any clue ? Your help will be greatly appreciated !

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: 

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"bookings", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

code for testing:

```
require 'test_helper'
    class BookingEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
        def setup
            @user = users(:michael)
        end

        test "unsucessful edit" do 
          log_in_as(@user)
          get edit_booking_path(@booking)
          assert_template 'bookings/edit'
          patch booking_path(@booking), booking: {date_of_tour: "2017-05-06", hotel_name: " ", hotel_address:"dadsada das",phone_number:12345678901 , number_of_pax:34 , pick_up_time: "9:00"}
          assert_template 'bookings/edit'
        end
    end
```

routes: `resources :bookings, only: [:show,:new, :create, :edit, :update,:destroy]`

booking model : **belongs_to :user**

user model:  **has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy**

booking_controller.rb

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:show, :edit,:create, :destroy]

  def show
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def create
    @booking = current_user.bookings.build(booking_params) 
    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "You have submited the information successfully!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @booking = current_user.bookings.find_by(params[:id])
    if @booking.update_attributes(booking_params)
      flash[:success] = "information updated"
      redirect_to @booking
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:date_of_tour,:hotel_address,:hotel_name,:phone_number,:number_of_pax,:pick_up_time)
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to set `@booking` to some value in the tests before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying

```
edit_booking_path(@booking)
```

But @booking hasn't been defined and the path helper can't generate the url for a booking that doesn't exist.

You have to create an instance of Booking before you attempt to use it.

Comment: Oh Thank you, i should define @booking = bookings(:most_recent)